# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS res-113

Tags: java, android

This question has been asked several times, but none of the proposed answers worked for me.

When I run my App in android studio on an emulator, it works fine, and when I run it on my phone (LG G4) it works as well. The problem appears when I try to run it on my friends phone (Nexus 6P).

It had previously run on that phone as well, until I made some changes and added the bitcoinj library in the dependencies folder. My guess is therefore that this library is causing some problems. Running the app on a Nexus 6P emulator works fine though.

In previous solutions to this error it was suggested that this can happen if my app is not compatible with the CPU architecture of the phone (ARM vs x86). However, this is weird since both Nexus 6P and LG G4 use ARM Snapdragon CPUs.

Further, the proposed solution, adding this to your build file does not work at all:

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
```

I am completely stuck and have no ideas how to approach this problem.